# Does AWS GuardDuty monitor traffic through an ELB?

Tags: amazon-web-services, network-monitoring

I've been trying to find a definitive answer to this question for a while. I would expect the answer to be "yes" but it does not align with what I see in practice. From the docs GuardDuty "[identifies threats by continuously monitoring the network activity and account behavior within the AWS environment.](https://aws.amazon.com/guardduty/)" From the diagram on that page, this includes VPC flow logs.

However, I've never seen a GuardDuty finding involving port probs (or any other kind of inbound Recon/UnauthorizedAccess alerts) against any of our instances behind an ELB or against the ELB itself. I do believe we have them locked down fairly well but I would expect to see port probes against 443 at least. (Not that I want them mind you. But it is public facing...)

Does AWS GuardDuty monitor and alert on traffic to and through an ELB?

*We are using Classic ELBs if that helps.

**Update**

I did open up port 443 to the world on an inconsequential server behind an ELB. I did start getting alerts on the instance but not the ELB. However having anything hit that server from anywhere other than the ELB is likely outside GuardDuty's normal activity baseline and could be enough to trigger it.

I'm still searching for an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Guard Duty monitors all traffic inside your VPC. It uses flow logs, CloudTrail, and DNS logs, but as it consumes that information at source from the hyperplane you don't actually need to have flow logs or CloudTrail turned on. I have no written source for that, it came from an AWS solution architect.

AWS Shield is integrated with CloudFront and load balancers, and may be preventing some bad actors reaching your instances.

I've seen Guard Duty alert on port probes, open security groups for RDP, all sorts of things. I've seen https probes against my web server which is behind CloudFlare, which isn't a load balancer but is effectively a reverse proxy. I turn off the low priority alerts as they were just getting annoying and didn't represent any real kind of threat.